# API Gateway authentication through Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I am using API-Gateway for exposing Lambda activity. Now, this API-Gateway needs to secure by TOKEN. I am using API-GATEWAY Authorizers for authentication.

I created a simple lambda function that returns `"AuthPolicy"` and it validates that request has a correct token on not. 
I linked that Lambda function with the Auth module. If I am invoking TEST through authorizers console, I am getting 200 success response but when I am invoking through postman, I am getting  `"Message": "User is not authorized to access this resource".`

Please let me know my missing configuration and code. **I am using Java code in Lambda.**

**Error on POSTMAN** "Message": `"User is not authorized to access this resource".`

Comment: do you send the auth token? Please post your request and Handler code

Comment: Could you please post your Lambda code so that we can see what it is expecting? My guess is that you are not sending a valid token through Postman.